# Subshell Job Clarification

Tags: xorg, job-control, subshell

I run the command `(Xorg & sleep 3; xeyes) &` to test Xorg, and group it into a single subshell background job to make management easy. This works properly, and opens xeyes in the new Xorg session after 3 seconds.

Upon running the command, I'll get an output such as the following:

`[1] 635`

After running `ps -ef` to check new processes, I'll get an output like the following:

```
root    635    361    0    4:52    tty1    00:00:00    -bash
root    636    365    0    4:52    tty2    00:00:00    /usr/lib/Xorg
root    639    365    0    4:52    tty1    00:00:00    xeyes
```

This seems to be a pretty standard output, and as expected.
After verifying my X server works as expected, I attempt to kill this group with `kill %1`. Upon running this, my processes now look as follows:

```
root    636    1    0    4:52    tty2    00:00:00    /usr/lib/Xorg
```

Why has Xorg failed to exit? Why has the subshell exited successfully, closing xeyes correctly, but not brought Xorg along with it? Why has the parent process of Xorg now changed to 1 instead of the subshell? Shouldn't the subshell send a kill signal to all of its child processes upon exit?

Additionally, if I kill the group instead with `kill 635`, which many resources say should be equivalent to `kill %1`, my process state is even more bizzare:

```
root    636    1    0    4:52    tty2    00:00:00    /usr/lib/Xorg
root    639    1    0    4:52    tty1    00:00:00    xeyes
```

What??? Why have both processes failed to exit now, and are now children of PID 1? What's going on here, and what am I doing wrong?

An in-depth explanation of what exactly is going on here would be appreciated, in addition to just telling me what to do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to observe job control, you'd want to use the `-j` option to `ps` which will list the process group id and session id.

Here, I see:

```
[...]
UID        PID  PPID  PGID   SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas  6805  4172  6805  6805  0 06:47 pts/7    00:00:00 /bin/zsh
chazelas  6825  6805  6825  6805  0 06:48 pts/7    00:00:00 xeyes
root      6826  6825  6826  6826  0 06:48 tty2     00:00:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :4
[...]
```

You see `Xorg` is a child of `xeyes` as my shell is a bit more optimised than `bash` and runs `xeyes` in the subshell's process as it's the last command of the subshell. And no, a subshell is not going to kill its children when it terminates, that would render the shell unusable (and here it's obvious it couldn't as the subshell has been replaced by `xeyes`).

The same in `bash`:

```
$ ps -Afj
[...]
UID        PID  PPID  PGID   SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas  7230  6805  7230  6805  0 06:54 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
chazelas  7246  7230  7246  6805  0 06:54 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
root      7247  7246  7247  7247  2 06:54 tty2     00:00:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :4
chazelas  7274  7246  7246  6805  0 06:54 pts/7    00:00:00 xeyes
[...]
```

There's an extra useless `bash` process that just waits for `xeyes` to terminate and won't do anything afterwards, but otherwise it's the same as in `zsh`, you see that a new process group has been created by the shell (6825 for `zsh`, `7246` for `bash`), but `Xorg` is not in that process group.

That's not because of the `&` after `Xorg`, commands started in a subshell are not started in a new job, that's because `Xorg` itself starts a whole new session itself (let alone a process group) to attach that tty2 terminal.

So as `Xorg` has removed itself from the process group, doing that `kill %1` won't kill it.

Note that `kill %1` sends a SIGTERM signal to the job's *process group*, not an individual pid. To send a signal to a process group you need:

```
kill -- -7246
```

Which in my case above would have killed pids 7246 (bash subshell) and 7274 (`xeyes`), but not `Xorg` (7247) as it's not in the 7246 process group.

Comment: Appreciate it! All that you've said makes sense, but how would I go about doing what I'm looking to do (run multiple commands asynchronously in a single job)?

Is what I'm looking to do even possible, or logical?

Comment: @quixotrykd, your approach is right in general, but not for `Xorg`. For `Xorg`, you'd probably want to use frameworks like `xinit`